# Linear Regression: Fails to identify sklearn

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, linear-regression

When I execute the below command, I am getting an `AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'typeDict'`. I upgraded numpy to the latest version as recommended (current version after upgrade=1.24.4), and installed sklearn using conda, but still the error persists. How to resolve this?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model
```

Error details as below:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[4], line 3
      1 import pandas as pd
      2 import numpy as np
----> 3 from sklearn import linear_model

File c:\python\python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py:82
     80 from . import _distributor_init  # noqa: F401
     81 from . import __check_build  # noqa: F401
---> 82 from .base import clone
     83 from .utils._show_versions import show_versions
     85 __all__ = ['calibration', 'cluster', 'covariance', 'cross_decomposition',
     86            'datasets', 'decomposition', 'dummy', 'ensemble', 'exceptions',
     87            'experimental', 'externals', 'feature_extraction',
   (...)
     96            'clone', 'get_config', 'set_config', 'config_context',
     97            'show_versions']

File c:\python\python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:20
     17 import numpy as np
     19 from . import __version__
---> 20 from .utils import _IS_32BIT
     22 _DEFAULT_TAGS = {
     23     'non_deterministic': False,
     24     'requires_positive_X': False,
   (...)
     35     'binary_only': False,
     36     'requires_fit': True}
     39 def clone(estimator, safe=True):

File c:\python\python38\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py:20
     18 import warnings
     19 import numpy as np
---> 20 from scipy.sparse import issparse
     22 from .murmurhash import murmurhash3_32
     23 from .class_weight import compute_class_weight, compute_sample_weight

File c:\python\python38\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\__init__.py:229
    223 # Original code by Travis Oliphant.
    224 # Modified and extended by Ed Schofield, Robert Cimrman,
    225 # Nathan Bell, and Jake Vanderplas.
    227 import warnings as _warnings
--> 229 from .base import *
    230 from .csr import *
    231 from .csc import *

File c:\python\python38\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\base.py:8
      6 from scipy._lib.six import xrange
      7 from scipy._lib._numpy_compat import broadcast_to
----> 8 from .sputils import (isdense, isscalarlike, isintlike,
      9                       get_sum_dtype, validateaxis, check_reshape_kwargs,
     10                       check_shape, asmatrix)
     12 __all__ = ['spmatrix', 'isspmatrix', 'issparse',
     13            'SparseWarning', 'SparseEfficiencyWarning']
     16 class SparseWarning(Warning):

File c:\python\python38\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\sputils.py:17
     11 __all__ = ['upcast', 'getdtype', 'isscalarlike', 'isintlike',
     12            'isshape', 'issequence', 'isdense', 'ismatrix', 'get_sum_dtype']
     14 supported_dtypes = ['bool', 'int8', 'uint8', 'short', 'ushort', 'intc',
     15                     'uintc', 'longlong', 'ulonglong', 'single', 'double',
     16                     'longdouble', 'csingle', 'cdouble', 'clongdouble']
---> 17 supported_dtypes = [np.typeDict[x] for x in supported_dtypes]
     19 _upcast_memo = {}
     22 def upcast(*args):

File c:\python\python38\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\sputils.py:17, in <listcomp>(.0)
     11 __all__ = ['upcast', 'getdtype', 'isscalarlike', 'isintlike',
     12            'isshape', 'issequence', 'isdense', 'ismatrix', 'get_sum_dtype']
     14 supported_dtypes = ['bool', 'int8', 'uint8', 'short', 'ushort', 'intc',
     15                     'uintc', 'longlong', 'ulonglong', 'single', 'double',
     16                     'longdouble', 'csingle', 'cdouble', 'clongdouble']
---> 17 supported_dtypes = [np.typeDict[x] for x in supported_dtypes]
     19 _upcast_memo = {}
     22 def upcast(*args):

File c:\python\python38\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py:320, in __getattr__(attr)
    317     from .testing import Tester
    318     return Tester
--> 320 raise AttributeError("module {!r} has no attribute "
    321                      "{!r}".format(__name__, attr))

AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'typeDict'
```

Answer (score -2):

The error you're encountering is due to the np.typeDict attribute being used in the SciPy library, which no longer exists in newer versions of NumPy (your version is 1.24.4). The np.typeDict has been deprecated and removed, which is causing compatibility issues with the version of SciPy you are using.

Ensure that SciPy is updated to the latest version compatible with your NumPy version. Sometimes, older versions of libraries rely on deprecated features of other libraries. Updating SciPy might resolve this issue if the newer version has removed the use of np.typeDict.